# htaccess rewriterule, [R,L=301] flags does not stop it. Why?

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, https, url-rewriting

The beginning of .htaccess is

```
RewriteEngine On

#begin of rules for administration folder, redirect to https, if not https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/administration
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L=301]
#end of rules for administration folder

#===no rules for /administration folder below this line===
#the rest part of .htaccess
```

Why does the rest part of .htaccess still performs for `https://www.mydomain.com/administration/index.php` ? How to stop the performing of the rest part of .htaccess file for urls that follow to administration folder? What's wrong in my code?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this line on top of your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^administration - [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had simmilar issue these days and I got a really interesting answer from the user DaveRandom in the PHP chat:

"Basically, mod_rewrite effectively runs in a loop (this isn't really true but effectively that's what it does) and the [L] flag is like a "continue" statement in PHP (it stops processing the rules below in the current iteration but it will then start processing the rules again from the top). So in your rules, the first iteration was matching the first rule, and then the second iteration skipped the first rule (it produced the same output as the input) and then matched the second rule."

**Possible Solution**: "if you are using apache 2.4 using [END] instead of [L] would be a fix".

Answer (score -1):

It is because you have syntax error. .htaccess will ignore erroring lines

Change this:-

```
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L=301]
```

To this:-

```
RewriteRule .? https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
```

Comment: Removing the `L` flag can cause problems sometimes.

Comment: Really? I've never had a problem. Under what circumstances?

Comment: You will almost always want to use [R] in conjunction with [L] (that is, use [R,L]) because on its own, the [R] flag prepends http://thishost[:thisport] to the URI, but then passes this on to the next rule in the ruleset, which can often result in 'Invalid URI in request' warnings. (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r)